# How to view and re-edit formulas in tables of LibreOffice or OpenOffice Writer text documents?

Tags: formula, openoffice-writer, libreoffice-writer

In LibreOffice or OpenOffice Writer, editing a text document, I can create a table and add a formula to a table cell by entering an equal sign. However, I cannot find a way to view and re-edit the formula once it's been entered.

[LibreOffice help](https://help.libreoffice.org/Writer/Calculating_in_Text_Documents) only explains how to enter a formula, but doesn't mention viewing or re-editing it.

How to view and re-edit formulas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [LibreOffice help](https://help.libreoffice.org/Writer/Calculating_in_Text_Documents) isn't precise enough at this point. You can do it by selecting the table cell with your formula and then press <kbd>F2</kbd>.

To do a test I created a 3x3 table in LO Writer, typed `= sqrt 9` in the first cell and pressed <kbd>Enter</kbd>. Now a `3` appears in this cell. By pressing <kbd>F2</kbd> the formula bar is shown up and I can do my edit (see selection).

[image]

Comment: This describes how to insert a new formula, but it doesn’t work for viewing and editing an existing one.

Comment: I edited my answer just to be clear (LO Version: 6.2.1.2 (x64)).